# trigonometric series with nonnegative coefficients and prescribed values

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Given real numbers $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$ and $r_1$, $\dots$, $r_n$ (with reasonable restrictions), is there a trigonometric series $T(x)=\sum_k a_k \cos(kx)$ with $a_k\ge 0$ such that
$$
|T(x_i)-r_i|<\epsilon
$$
for all $i$?

Comment: If  $\{1,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is rationally independent, then the answer is yes with a single term.

Comment: On the other hand, the answer is clearly no if, say, $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 2 \pi$, and $|r_1 - r_2| > 2 \epsilon$. You don't include a quantifier on $\epsilon$ but I'm guessing.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas  yes, by Kronecker's theorem. But the linearly independent condition is too special for me.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you are right. that's why I said "with reasonable restrictions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDITED]** $\def\conv{\mathop{\rm conv}\nolimits}$The answer is **yes** if $x_1,\dots,x_n\in(0,\pi]$ are pairwise distinct (are  these `reasonable restrictions'?).

Consider a set $C=\{x(t)=(\cos tx_1,\dots,\cos tx_n)\colon t\in\mathbb Z\}\subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $D$ be the closure of the convex hull of $C$.

I claim that $0$ is the interior point of $D$. This yields that for every sufficiently small $r_1,\dots,r_n$ there are required coefficients $a_j\geq 0$ (at most $n+1$ of them nonzero) summing up to $1$. An appropriate scaling then completes the proof

Firstly, notice that 
$$
  \frac1N\sum_{t=1}^N x(t)\to 0, \quad N\to+\infty,
$$
so $0\in D$. The only case to exclude is that $0$ is a boundary point of $D$, or --- that there esists a supporting hyperplane of $D$ passing through $0$, or --- that there exist some nontrivial coefficients $\alpha_i$ such that
$$
  f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\cos tx_j\geq 0
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb Z$.

So we need to show that it is impossible. Assume first that $f$ is not identically zero. Then there exists some $n$ such that $\delta=\sum_{t=1}^n  f(t)>0$. This yields that $\sum_{t=1}^N f(t)\geq \delta$ for all $N\geq n$. This is false, since 
$$
  \sum_{t=1}^N f(t)
  =\sum_j\alpha_j\sum_{t=1}^N\cos tx_j
  =\sum_j\alpha_j\frac{\sin(N+1/2)x_j-\sin x_j/2}{\sin x_j/2},
$$
and all fractions can simultaneously be made very small by Kronecker's theorem.

We are left to show that $f$ is not identically zero. Indeed, it is a nontrivial linear combination of the sequences $(\exp(\pm itx_j))$ which are independent by Vandermonde.

Comment: I think, points with integer $t$  are not always dense on this curve, even if $n=1$ and $x_1=\pi/17$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Oh! Yes, so the condition is that $\pi$ is not in their rational linear hull, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: It seems that after replacing integrals by sums everything works.

Comment: by Kronecker you may make cosines close to 1, not to 0

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I see what you claim, but I do not see how is it implied by Kronecker. Sum of coefficients is in general not 0, right?

Comment: Also I think that $x$ and $2\pi-x$ are not really distinct in this context, so better to say that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ belong to $(0,\pi]$.

Comment: Ah, I probably got your point: $\sin \frac x2\sum_{t=1}^N \cos tx_i=\sin(Nx+\frac x2)-\sin \frac x2$, and this is pretty close to 0 when $Nx$ is almost divisible by $2\pi$.

Comment: Sorry; surely I meant $x_j\in(0,\pi]$, since $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos x$ I've expanded the last paragraph into two paragraphs...